Using a Y switch at amplifier output
I want to use 2 Y switch at the output of a stereo audio amplifier (1 per channel) to switch between two speakers. Both speakers embed passive crossover circuits (so resistance, capacitors and coils).
Should I be concerned about what I want to do ? (outside of using a proper switch rated for the proper current)
Should I switch the speakers only when the amp is turned off ? OR should I find a switch with a third position that wouldn't be connected to anything to have a kind of "buffer" between the two to avoid shorting the speakers and putting them for a short period of time in parallel ? Should I ground the speaker to empty the load of the embedded capacitor ? Should I ground the neutral position with a resistor ?
Anything else I should worry about ?
I google searched, but only find recommendation for dedicated products that are really expensive (audiophoolery ?). And been in the EE hobby years ago, but forgot a lot of theory meanwhile as I didn't used it anymore.
Thank you in advance for your help !

If you're worried about the transient open circuit during switching damaging the amplifier, that is very unlikely for a well-designed amp. Use an ordinary toggle switch (which can flip in just a few milliseconds), not a knife switch which can be left in an unconnected state.

@DrMoishePippik thank you for the clarification !

How much power are you looking to switch?  100W?  You can easily do this with a STDP relay per channel, or a DPDT to switch both channels at once.  You do not need to worry about the crossover circuity, or discharging the caps in them.
As for turning the amp off when switching loads, you'll most likely be fine if the amp is of reasonable design and not some delicate hi-fi tuned to the reactance of the cables, works best on 117V but not 120V sort of thing.
If you are of moderate concern, you can turn the volume down before switching speakers.
Here are two examples of how to wire this up, either as a single channel at a time, or both channels together.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I think you'd want a DPDT switch, to switch both channels with a single switch.

@PeterBennett Good point!  I'll update the answer.

Thank you for your answer ! The amp is a class A 2*30watt into 8ohm speakers. It's usually around 1/3 of the volume on a logarithmic potentiometer.

@EmmanuelIstace Yeah, I would not worry about that at all.  It's very similar to what the amplifiers do internally anyway.  When you hear that click right before you hear sound, that's the relay connecting the speakers.

@Aaron thank you, sorry for the delay :) if we add the passive crossover of each speaker in the schematic, does it change anything ?
